# Dynamically render data and render components conditionally: React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, setstate

I am trying to implement a details page where I am displaying details corresponding to each items. Each item will have its own details which will be shown on "Show Details" and details of corresponding item should be hidden when "Hide Details" is clicked. There are two components Item and ItemDetailViewer that shows individual items and its details correspondingly. I am unable to implement the Show/Hide for each Item component.

Also on click of show details of each item the details should be displayed in a table. The items for this table are different for different items ; this should be populated dynamically.

Can someone help me here?

Code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/summer-surf-4h0g6

### App Component

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./styles.css";
import ItemViewer from "./Item";

const item1 = ["i1d1", "i2d2", "i3d3"];
const item2 = ["i2d1", "i2d2", "i2d3"];
const item3 = ["i3d1", "i3d2", "i3d3"];

const item1Detail = [
  { age: 21, email: "wassasaasif@email.com" },
  { age: 19, email: "dsdddee@email.com" }
];
const item2Detail = [
  { id: 24, phone: "454654654644" },
  { id: 29, phone: "465654654643" }
];
const item3Detail = [
  { index: 25, address: "dsdsdsdsds" },
  { index: 39, address: "trytytytyy" }
];
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      item1: [],
      item2: [],
      item3: [],
      item1Detail: [],
      item2Detail: [],
      item3Detail: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      item1,
      item2,
      item3,
      item1Detail,
      item2Detail,
      item3Detail
    });
  }

  render() {
    let {
      item1,
      item2,
      item3,
      item1Detail,
      item2Detail,
      item3Detail
    } = this.state;
    return (
      <>
        <ItemViewer
          index="1"
          item="item1"
          itemData={item1}
          itemDetailData={item1Detail}
        />
        <ItemViewer
          index="2"
          item="item2"
          itemData={item2}
          itemDetailData={item2Detail}
        />
        <ItemViewer
          index="3"
          item="item3"
          itemData={item3}
          itemDetailData={item3Detail}
        />
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

### ItemViewer Component

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ItemDetailViewer from "./ItemDetailViewer";

const ItemViewer = props => {
  const [isitem1, setItem1] = useState(false);
  const [isitem2, setItem2] = useState(false);
  const [isitem3, setItem3] = useState(false);
  const [openDetails, setOpenDetails] = useState(false);
  function renderItems(list, itemType, itemDetailData) {
    if (list && list.length > 0) {
      return (
        <>
          <ul>
            {list.map(function(item) {
              return <li key={item}>{item}</li>;
            })}
          </ul>
          {!openDetails && (
            <button onClick={() => handleClick(itemType)}>View Details</button>
          )}
          {openDetails && (
            <button onClick={() => handleClick(itemType)}>Hide Details</button>
          )}
          {isitem1 && (
            <ItemDetailViewer showDetais={openDetails} data={itemDetailData} />
          )}
          {isitem2 && (
            <ItemDetailViewer showDetais={openDetails} data={itemDetailData} />
          )}
          {isitem3 && (
            <ItemDetailViewer showDetais={openDetails} data={itemDetailData} />
          )}
        </>
      );
    } else {
      return <p>No Items Found</p>;
    }
  }
  function handleClick(item) {
    if (item === "item1") {
      setItem1(true);
      setOpenDetails(!openDetails);
    }
    if (item === "item2") {
      setItem2(true);
      setOpenDetails(!openDetails);
    }
    if (item === "item3") {
      setItem3(true);
      setOpenDetails(!openDetails);
    }
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <span>
        {props.index}: {props.item}
      </span>
      <div>{renderItems(props.itemData, props.item, props.itemDetailData)}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ItemViewer;
```

### ItemDetail Component

```
import React from "react";

const ItemDetailViewer = props => {
  return (
    <>
      {
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th>Key corresponding to each item</th>
              <td>Value corresponding to each item</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      }
    </>
  );
};
export default ItemDetailViewer;
```

Comment: Is this what you want to do? Check out my answer.

Comment: I have implemented show/hide feature.

Comment: @kooskoos Thank you. Might I know what was wrong?

Comment: I have implemented everything you want. Check out my solution.

Comment: @kooskoos Thank you so much; Just want to know what was wrong with my SHow/Hide?

Comment: You were always setting it to true, whereas you should toggle it to true/ false. And the new solution also populates the data dynamically, let me know if that's what you wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this updated sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-wildflower-ek8ed

Comment: on click of a particular item's show details, its details should be shown on a table(inside ItemDetailViewer). Each item's detail is present inside App component

Comment: Check out the sandbox above for complete solution

Comment: @kookoos, actually table data is different from what I was expecting. Would require a table for each object inside of array.Would you help. For item1 it should be two tables on click of View Details

Comment: Can you show a sample output, the way you want it to be?

Answer (score 1):

```
import React from "react";

const ItemDetailViewer = props => {
  const { data } = props;
  return (
    <div className={"container"}>
      {data.map((detail, index) => (
        <table key={index}>
          {Object.keys(detail).map((key, index) => (
            <div className={"records"}>
              <span>{key}</span>
              <span>:{detail[key]}</span>
            </div>
          ))}
        </table>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
export default ItemDetailViewer;
```

styles.css

```
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.records {
  display: flex;
  width: 300px;
}

table {
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  margin-right: 1em;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}
```

Screenshot of the exact output you want

[image]
This should get you as many no of tables as the number of objects you have in the array.

I have modified the sandbox, check it if this is what you want https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-wildflower-ek8ed

Comment: Is this what you are expecting?

Comment: https://draw.chat/BD50A9C771B802009AF:i8ahq0n7#p1,0,0,r0,s1    Check this

Comment: I have modified the code to achieve the output you want. Hope that helps:)

Comment: Just great! Thanks